# Same Pandas Commands works in one place but not another?

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

I Have an Scikit-Learn Transformer like below:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class ScoreTransformer(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def purchase_date_score(self, purchases):
        purchases['date_x'] = pd.to_datetime(purchases['FinishDate'])
        purchases['date_rank'] = purchases.sort_values(['uid','date_x'], ascending=False).groupby('uid')['date_x'].rank("dense", ascending=False).astype(int)

        print(f'step1 -----\n{purchases.head()}')
        df2 = purchases[purchases.groupby("bid")['uid'].transform('size') > 20].reset_index(drop=True)

        print(f'step2 -----\n{df2.head()}')
        df2 = df2[df2.groupby("uid")['bid'].transform('size') > 10].reset_index(drop=True)

        print(f'step3 -----\n{df2.head()}')
        df2 = df2[['uid', 'bid', 'date_rank']]
        df2['normal_rank'] = df2[['uid', 'date_rank']].groupby('uid')['date_rank'].transform(lambda x: round(x * 2 / x.max() + 3))

        print(f'step4 -----\n{df2.head()}')

        return df2.drop(['date_rank'], axis=1)

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return self.purchase_date_score(X)
```

and I use this Transformer within a pipeline like this:

```
ranking_score_pipeline = Pipeline(([
    ('score', ScoreTransformer())
]))

data = ranking_score_pipeline.fit_transform(data)
```

When I run this code in my Google-Colab notebook I get this output:
[image: Colab Output]

**BUT** when I run the SAME code on my VSCODE I get this:
[image: VSCODE Output]

DO you have any idea why?!
I have checked everything even python and pandas versions between environments and they are the same in both places.

Here's a small sample set of the data (Pandas DataFrame) that I use in this task:

```
    uid bid FinishDate

0   41,5,2013-09-14 10:44:59.877
1   43,37,2013-09-21 11:53:20.193
2   43,45,2013-09-21 12:01:42.390
3   41,99,2013-11-18 18:37:52.190
4   75,99,2013-12-19 09:24:55.717
```

Comment: In `step 2`, what is the meaning of `purchases[purchases.groupby("\`")`. There's no column named `\``. I imagine you inadvertently mangled something there. Do you mean `uid`?

Comment: Ooops! It was "bid"! Thanks :)

Comment: Ok. But I'm assuming that was an error in this post, not in your actual code. Anyway, are you sure you are passing the exact same `df` to `fit_transform` in both cases? My guess would be "no", because your code in vscode seems to be working just fine. It's just that the `df` passed there apparently has no groups with `size`  > `10`, leading to only `False` vals for `df2.groupby("uid")['bid'].transform('size') > 10`. I.e. you are selecting 0 rows from the `df`. With the small sample, you already reach 0 rows at step 2, since no `size` will be `> 20`. Try e.g. `> 1` and you should get data.

Comment: Yea you were right! the data in my code wasn't updated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug here!
It was because of the different pandas versions that were used in both systems.
In google colab notebook (where I developed the transformer), I had the latest version of pandas installed. But on my local system my pandas version was a little older and did not support this command: `df2 = df2[['uid', 'bid', 'date_rank']]`

So it returned an empty DataFrame.